# MySQL, how to get daterange in thos format: YYYY-MM-DD HH

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a datetime field in mysql.

I need to select between these two date ranges in this format YYYY-MM-DD HH

"2012-12-20 10" and "2012-12-23 15"

How can I do this in mysql where utcdt is my datetime field?

```
SELECT DISTINCT utcdt
FROM rtb
WHERE 
utcdt>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-12-20 10") and utcdt<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-12-23 15")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN` and `STR_TO_DATE` as below:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT utcdt
 FROM rtb
 WHERE 
 utcdt BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-20 10', '%Y-%m-%d %h') 
       and STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-23 15', '%Y-%m-%d %h')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's numerous ways to do this. [Yogendra Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044971/mysql-how-to-get-daterange-in-thos-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hh#14045023) already showed one option. You could also do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT utcdt
FROM rtb
WHERE 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP( utcdt ) BETWEEN
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-12-20 10") AND
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2012-12-23 15");
```

... for instance. Or, you could even do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT utcdt
FROM rtb
WHERE 
utcdt BETWEEN
    "2012-12-20 10" AND
    "2012-12-23 15";
```

... in other words, not even the need to convert to a unix timestamp first.

And so, in the same fashion you tried, even:

```
SELECT DISTINCT utcdt
FROM rtb
WHERE 
utcdt >= "2012-12-20 10" AND
utcdt <= "2012-12-23 15";
```